# Trying to retrieve previous iteration of foreach loop data in future iterations

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a foreach loop that requires a calculation of data that includes a data point from the iteration before the current.

e.g Performance = Price1 / Price0

Where Price1 can be found in the CURRENT iteration of the foreach loop

Where Price0 can be found in the PREVIOUS iteration of the foreach loop

This is currently what I've put together

View

```
@foreach ($arr as $key => $currentValue) {
                $previousValue = null;
    
                if ($key > 0) {
                $previousValue = $arr[$key-1];
                    }
                }
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                <td>{{ $currentValue }}</td>
                <td>{{ $previousValue }}</td>
            </tr>
                @endforeach
```

Controller

```
$Prices = Price::query()
                        ->orderBy('date','desc')
                        ->pluck('price');

$arr = $Prices;

        foreach ($arr as $key => $currentValue) {
        $previousValue = null;
    
        if ($key > 0) {
            $previousValue = $arr[$key-1];
        }

    }
```

Currently, this outputs the below table

| Iteration | Current Value | Previous Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.75000000 | 3.50000000 |
| 2 | 3.65000000 | 3.50000000 |
| 3 | 3.50000000 | 3.50000000 |
| 4 | 3.15035915 | 3.50000000 |

However I would like it to output

| Iteration | Current Value | Previous Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.75000000 | 3.65000000 |
| 2 | 3.65000000 | 3.50000000 |
| 3 | 3.50000000 | 3.15035915 |
| 4 | 3.15035915 | 3.00000000 |

Comment: How can you get the previous value for the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   @foreach ($arr as $key => $currentValue)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
            <td>{{ $key > 0 ? $arr[$key - 1] : 'none' }}</td>
            <td>{{ $currentValue }}</td>
        </tr>
            @endforeach
```

This fixed the looping issue.

Comment: A bit shorter `{{ $arr[$key - 1] ?? 'none' }}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).